# How to use fiftyone for exploring the instance segmentation of custom coco data?

Tags: coco, fiftyone

How to use *fiftyone* for exploring the instance segmentation of custom coco data? It has documentation for coco dataset but I couldn't find any resource for custom coco dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You can find documentation for importing custom `COCODetectionDatasets` [here](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/dataset_creation/datasets.html#cocodetectiondataset).

In short, as long as your data follows the expected COCO format:

```
{
    "info": {...},
    "licenses": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike License",
            "url": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.0/",
        },
        ...
    ],
    "categories": [
        ...
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "cat",
            "supercategory": "animal",
            "keypoints": ["nose", "head", ...],
            "skeleton": [[12, 14], [14, 16], ...]
        },
        ...
    ],
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "license": 1,
            "file_name": "<filename0>.<ext>",
            "height": 480,
            "width": 640,
            "date_captured": null
        },
        ...
    ],
    "annotations": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "image_id": 1,
            "category_id": 2,
            "bbox": [260, 177, 231, 199],
            "segmentation": [...],
            "keypoints": [224, 226, 2, ...],
            "num_keypoints": 10,
            "score": 0.95,
            "area": 45969,
            "iscrowd": 0
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The segmentation field format is defined [here](https://cocodataset.org/#format-data).

Then you can load it into FiftyOne with the following Python code:

```py
import fiftyone as fo

name = "my-dataset"
dataset_dir = "/path/to/coco-detection-dataset"

# Create the dataset
dataset = fo.Dataset.from_dir(
    dataset_dir=dataset_dir,
    dataset_type=fo.types.COCODetectionDataset,
    name=name,
)

# View summary info about the dataset
print(dataset)

# Print the first few samples in the dataset
print(dataset.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by using [COCODetectionDatasetImporter](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/api/fiftyone.utils.coco.html#fiftyone.utils.coco.COCODetectionDatasetImporter) Class and set `label_types=["detections","segmentations"]` for seeing mask annotated images